# Gear down on climb out

Tags: landing-gear, boeing-787

i saw on a live stream from Manchester, that a Virgin A330, left the landing Gear down for 2-3 Minutes after take off, a smiliar scenario i saw on a stream from Heathrow, where British Airways and Virgin 787s,left the gear down for a while, a Chatter said hot breaks, but how is this possible on take off?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com. I am sure this question has be answered before on this website.

Comment: See  "[Why would a pilot leave the gear down after takeoff for extended period of time](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/54690/19)" and "[Why did my flight leave the gear down for the first 10 minutes of flight? duplicate](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/98073/19)"